# How to use Spring Boot/Spring Security to wrap a call to an OAuth2 bearer token request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm stuck with the following problem: in order to access an online API, I need to get authenticated. Right now, I do everything in my own code:

1. Call the token URL for a bearer token
2. Get the bearer token
3. Call the real service with the bearer token
4. Get the result

Here's the code:

```
@RestController
public class RandomController {

    private final Random random;

    public RandomController(Random random) {
        this.random = random;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = GET)
    public int random(@RequestParam(value = "limit", defaultValue = "100") int limit) {
        String bearerToken = getBearerToken();
        int[] bounds = getBounds(bearerToken);
        return computeRandom(bounds[0], bounds[1]);
    }

    private String getBearerToken() {
        RestTemplate tokenTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("client_id", "my id");
        body.add("client_secret", "my secret");
        body.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> res = tokenTemplate.exchange(
                "https://bearer.token/get", POST, entity, String.class);
        Map<String, Object> map = new BasicJsonParser().parseMap(res.getBody());
        return (String) map.get("access_token");
    }

    private int[] getBounds(String bearerToken) {
        RestTemplate configurationTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> res = configurationTemplate.exchange(
                "https://configurations.com/bounds", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        Map<String, Object> map = new BasicJsonParser().parseMap(res.getBody());
        Map<String, Long> value = (Map<String, Long>) map.get("value");
        int lowerBound = value.get("lower").intValue();
        int upperBound = value.get("upper").intValue();
        return new int[]{lowerBound, upperBound};
    }

    private int computeRandom(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
        int difference = upperBound - lowerBound;
        int raw = random.nextInt(difference);
        return raw + lowerBound;
    }
}
```

It works, but I'm wasting a call to the token URL at every call. This is how I'd like it to work:

1. Call the real service
2. If getting a 401

   1. Call the token URL for a bearer token
   2. Get the bearer token
   3. Recall the service with the bearer token
3. Get the result

I could do that in my code, but I'm already using Spring Boot. I'm wondering how to achieve that. Is there an existing filter, interceptor, whatever?

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jny mentions, the class to use is [OAuth2RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html). However, its constructor requires an implementation of  [OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/resource/OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails.html).

Several implementation are available, the one that uses `client_credential` is `ClientCredentialsResourceDetails`. I was hoping that just adding `@EnableOAuth2Client` to my configuration class and configuring the required information in the `application.yml` would be enough:

```
security:
    oauth2:
        client:
            grant-type: client_credentials
            client-id: my id
            client-secret: my secret
            access-token-uri: https://bearer.token/get
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The reason can be found in class `OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(EnableOAuth2Client.class)
@Conditional(OAuth2ClientIdCondition.class)
public class OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnNotWebApplication
    protected static class SingletonScopedConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2.client")
        @Primary
        public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails oauth2RemoteResource() {
            ClientCredentialsResourceDetails details = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
            return details;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

It seems the Spring framework assumes - incorrectly, that only non-web application can use the client credentials authentication. Whereas in my case, that's the only way the provider offers.

The relevant snippet can be copy-pasted though :-)

My final code looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RandomApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RandomApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2.client")
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails() {
        return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate() {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(clientCredentialsResourceDetails());
    }

    @Bean
    Random random() {
        return new SecureRandom();
    }
}

@RestController
public class RandomController {

    private final OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate;
    private final Random random;

    public RandomController(OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate, Random random) {
        this.oAuth2RestTemplate = oAuth2RestTemplate;
        this.random = random;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = GET)
    public int random() {
        int[] bounds = getBounds();
        return computeRandom(bounds[0], bounds[1]);
    }

    private int[] getBounds() {
        ResponseEntity<String> res = oAuth2RestTemplate.getForEntity(
                "https://configurations.com/bounds", String.class);
        Map<String, Object> map = new BasicJsonParser().parseMap(res.getBody());
        Map<String, Long> value = (Map<String, Long>) map.get("value");
        int lowerBound = value.get("lower").intValue();
        int upperBound = value.get("upper").intValue();
        return new int[]{lowerBound, upperBound};
    }

    private int computeRandom(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
        int difference = upperBound - lowerBound;
        int raw = random.nextInt(difference);
        return raw + lowerBound;
    }
}
```

Notice that the controller gets much less boilerplate because I replaced the `RestTemplate` with `OAuth2RestTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [OAuth2RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html) from Spring Security. It should take care of getting token and caching it if possible. It should be configured in the config file and injected everywhere you make call to the API.

Comment: I'll upvote your answer because: a) it's the only one - thanks :) b) it got me rolling in the right direction.

Still, I was expecting something more detailed. I've finally found a way to achieve what I want with minimal code. I'll answer my own question below for the sake of documentation.